# Как представить результат запроса, состоящий из атрибутов 3 связанных моделей, в одном сериализаторе? Django REST API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm

Хочу сделать вывод представления `WheelsSupplesView` в json, которое содержит `queriset`. Мне необходимо отобразить поля из разных моделей в одном выводе. Проблема в том, что данные модели связаны следующим образом:

`StockType` - `Stock`: 1-M

`StockType` - `WheelsCharacter`: 1-1

Модель `WheelsCharacter` содержит поле `stock_type`, которое является внешним ключом на модель `StockType` (OneToOneField).

Модель `Stock` содержит поле `stock_type`, которое является внешним ключом на модель `StockType` (ForeignKey).

Мне нужно написать сериализатор, который смог бы преобразовать результат запроса к следующему виду:

```
[
{
    "stock_type": "Текст",
    "model_name": "Текст",
    "diameter": 50
    "width": 20
    "profile": 30
    "run_flat": True
    "marking_c": True
    "grade": 5.0
    "date": "2022-02-27",
    "number": 4
},
{
    "stock_type": "Текст2",
    "date": "2022-02-27",
    "model_name": "Текст2",
    "diameter": 51
    "width": 23
    "profile": 35
    "run_flat": True
    "marking_c": False
    "grade": 4.0
    "number": 3
}]
```

Пробовал различные варианты написания сериализаторов, а также способов получения данных путем смены основной модели в запросе, но так ничего и не помогло. Чаще всего ошибки сводятся к тому, что в выбранной в `queriset` модели отсутствует поле из другой модели.

**views.py**

```
class WheelsSupplesView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queriset = Stock.objects.prefetch_related('stock_type').select_related('stock_type__wheelscharacter').filter(Q(stock_type__item_type='Шина') | Q(stock_type__item_type='Колесо'))
        serializer = WheelsCharacterSupplesSerializer(queriset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**models.py**

```
class StockType(models.Model):
    item_type = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Тип')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Название')
    default_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Закупочная цена')
    sale_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Стоимость продажи', null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.item_type, self.name)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Товар'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Товар'
        ordering = ['name']


class Stock(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата операции')
    number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество')
    stock_type = models.ForeignKey('StockType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Товар')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.stock_type, self.date, self.number)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Запись со склада'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Записи со склада'
        ordering = ['date']

class WheelsCharacter(models.Model):
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Модель')
    diameter = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Диаметр')
    width = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Ширина')
    profile = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Профиль')
    run_flat = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Run flat')
    marking_c = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Маркировка С')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Статус')
    stock_type = models.OneToOneField('StockType', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Товар')
    winter = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Зима')
    grade = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Оценка')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.model_name, self.diameter, self.status)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Шина'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Шины'
        ordering = ['model_name']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось немного иначе, но работает
Вывод выглядит следующим образом:

```
"wheels": {
        "stock_type": "Текст",
        "model_name": "Текст",
        "diameter": 14,
        "width": 185,
        "profile": 65,
        "run_flat": false,
        "marking_c": false,
        "grade": 3.5,
        "winter": true,
        "status": "Статус"
    },
    "stock": [
        {
            "date": "2022-02-27",
            "number": 4
        },
        {
            "date": "2022-03-05",
            "number": 1
        }
    ]
```

**views.py**

```
class WheelsSupplesView(APIView):
def get(self, request):
    queriset = StockType.objects.prefetch_related('stock').select_related('wheels').filter(Q(item_type='Шина') | Q(item_type='Колесо'))
    serializer = WheelsCharacterSupplesSerializer(queriset, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

**serializers.py**

```
class WheelsCharacterSupplesSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class LocalStockSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

        class Meta:
            model = Stock
            fields = ('date', 'number')

wheels = WheelsCharacterSerializer()
stock = LocalStockSerializer(many=True)

class Meta:
    model = StockType
    fields = ('wheels', 'stock')
    depth = 1
```

**models.py**

```
class StockType(models.Model):
item_type = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Тип')
name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Название')
default_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Закупочная цена')
sale_price = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Стоимость продажи', null=True, blank=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s' % (self.item_type, self.name)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Товар'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Товар'
    ordering = ['name']


class Stock(models.Model):
date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name='Дата операции')
number = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Количество')
stock_type = models.ForeignKey('StockType', related_name='stock', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Товар')

def __str__(self):
    return '%s %s %s' % (self.stock_type, self.date, self.number)

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Склад'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Склад'
    ordering = ['date']


class WheelsCharacter(models.Model):
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Модель')
    diameter = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Диаметр')
    width = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Ширина')
    profile = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='Профиль')
    run_flat = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Run flat')
    marking_c = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Маркировка С')
    status = models.CharField(max_length=150, verbose_name='Статус')
    stock_type = models.OneToOneField('StockType', related_name='wheels', on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name='Товар')
    winter = models.BooleanField(verbose_name='Зима')
    grade = models.FloatField(verbose_name='Оценка')

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s %s' % (self.model_name, self.diameter, self.status)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Шина/Колесо'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Шины/Колеса'
        ordering = ['model_name']
```